# JavaScript function declaration as jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I declare my JS functions as jQuery functions?
My code is working but I want have only jQuery with no vanilla JS.
I know that is no point of doing this but I need to have only jQuery and no pure JavaScript.

Thanks for your help.

```
var slideOne = ["assets/slider-image-7.jpg", "assets/slider-image-6.jpg", "assets/slider-image-9.jpg", "assets/slider-image-8.jpg", "assets/slider-image-5.jpg"];
var slideTwo = ["assets/slider-image-4.jpg", "assets/slider-image-1.jpg", "assets/slider-image-2.jpg", "assets/slider-image-3.jpg"];
var firstSlide = document.querySelector(".first");
var secondSlide = document.querySelector(".second");

function rowOne() {
  for (var i = 0; i < slideOne.length; i++) {
    var picture = document.createElement("li");
    picture.classList.add("picture");
    picture.innerHTML = '<img src="' + slideOne[i] + '"/>';
    firstSlide.appendChild(picture);
  }
}

function rowTwo() {
  for (var i = 0; i < slideTwo.length; i++) {
    var picture = document.createElement("li");
    picture.classList.add("picture");
    picture.innerHTML = '<img src="' + slideTwo[i] + '"/>';
    secondSlide.appendChild(picture);
  }
} 

function moveLeftFirst() {
  $("ul.first > li:last-child").remove().prependTo(".first");
}

function moveRightFirst() {
  $("ul.first > li:first-child").remove().appendTo(".first");
}

function moveLeftSecond() {
  $("ul.second > li:last-child").remove().prependTo(".second");
}

function moveRightSecond() {
  $("ul.second > li:first-child").remove().appendTo(".second");
}

$(".previous").click(function () {
  moveLeftFirst();
  moveLeftSecond();
});

$(".next").click(function () {
  moveRightFirst();
  moveRightSecond();
});

rowOne();
rowTwo();
```

Comment: Your request is strange, jQuery *is* vanilla JS.

Comment: I'm really not clear if you are asking how to rewrite all this code to use jQuery instead of native functions, or if you want to rewrite it as a jQuery plugin. Either way, its horribly underresearched.

Comment: You have a number of functions there, which ones do you want to be "jQuery functions"? Because, for instance, `rowTwo` depends on global variables (`slideTwo`, `picture`, `secondSlide`), and thus would not be a good candidate for being a jQuery plugin (not to mention its use of DOM functions over jQuery).

Answer (score 1):

```js
const rowImages = ($el, images) =>$el.append(images.map(src => $("<li>", {
  class: `picture`,
  html: `<img src="${src}">`
})));
const move = ($el, isNext) => $el.find(`li:${isNext ? "first" : "last"}-child`).remove()[isNext ? 'appendTo' : 'prependTo']($el);

const $firstSlide = $(".first");
const $secondSlide = $(".second");

$(".previous, .next").on("click", function () {
  const isNext = $(this).is('.next');
  move($firstSlide, isNext);
  move($secondSlide, isNext);
});

rowImages($firstSlide, ["//placehold.it/50x50/0bf", "//placehold.it/50x50/f0b", "//placehold.it/50x50/fb0", "//placehold.it/50x50/bf0", "//placehold.it/50x50/0fb"]);
rowImages($secondSlide, ["//placehold.it/50x50/fb0",  "//placehold.it/50x50/0bf",  "//placehold.it/50x50/0fb" ,"//placehold.it/50x50/f0b", "//placehold.it/50x50/bf0"]);
```

```css
ul {padding:0; list-style:none; display:flex; }
```

```html
<ul class="first"></ul>
<ul class="second"></ul>

<button class="previous">PREV</button>
<button class="next">NEXT</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the following syntax:

- `document.querySelector` with `$`
- `document.createElement('li')` with `$('<li></li>')`
- `classList.add` with `addClass`
- `innerHTML` with `html`
- `appendChild` with `append`

So the final result will be:

```js
var slideOne = ["assets/slider-image-7.jpg", "assets/slider-image-6.jpg", "assets/slider-image-9.jpg", "assets/slider-image-8.jpg", "assets/slider-image-5.jpg"];
var slideTwo = ["assets/slider-image-4.jpg", "assets/slider-image-1.jpg", "assets/slider-image-2.jpg", "assets/slider-image-3.jpg"];
var firstSlide = $(".first");
var secondSlide = $(".second");

function rowOne() {
  for (var i = 0; i < slideOne.length; i++) {
    var picture = $("<li>")
      .addClass("picture")
      .html('<img src="' + slideOne[i] + '"/>');
    firstSlide.append(picture);
  }
}

function rowTwo() {
  for (var i = 0; i < slideTwo.length; i++) {
    var picture = $("<li></li>")
      .addClass("picture")
      .html('<img src="' + slideTwo[i] + '"/>');
    secondSlide.append(picture);
  }
} 

function moveLeftFirst() {
  $("ul.first > li:last-child").remove().prependTo(".first");
}

function moveRightFirst() {
  $("ul.first > li:first-child").remove().appendTo(".first");
}

function moveLeftSecond() {
  $("ul.second > li:last-child").remove().prependTo(".second");
}

function moveRightSecond() {
  $("ul.second > li:first-child").remove().appendTo(".second");
}

$(".previous").click(function () {
  moveLeftFirst();
  moveLeftSecond();
});

$(".next").click(function () {
  moveRightFirst();
  moveRightSecond();
});

rowOne();
rowTwo();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```